# Bluetooth battery level not showing up in status bar

Tags: battery, bluetooth, lineageos, bluetooth-le

I'm using Lineage OS 18.1 and a BLE Mouse that reports its battery level.

I can confirm that the battery level is reported correctly, by connecting it with my Linux computer:

[image: linux screenshot]

(See Devices: DIY Page Turner)

Also from the terminal:

```
[fedora@fedora ~]$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller 9C:B6:D0:94:27:00 Pairable: yes
[DIY Page Turner]# paired-devices
Device CC:50:E3:B6:91:00 DIY Page Turner
[DIY Page Turner]# menu gatt
Menu gatt:
Available commands:
-------------------
list-attributes [dev/local]                       List attributes
select-attribute <attribute/UUID>                 Select attribute
read [offset]                                     Read attribute value
...
[DIY Page Turner]# list-attributes CC:50:E3:B6:91:00
Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_50_E3_B6_91_00/service005f
    0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Battery Service
Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_50_E3_B6_91_00/service005f/char0060
    00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Battery Level
Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_50_E3_B6_91_00/service005f/char0060/desc0063
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_50_E3_B6_91_00/service005f/char0060/desc0062
    00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Characteristic Format
Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_50_E3_B6_91_00/service0028
    0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Device Information
Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_50_E3_B6_91_00/service0028/char002b
    00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Manufacturer Name String
Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_50_E3_B6_91_00/service0028/char0029
    00002a50-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    PnP ID
Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_50_E3_B6_91_00/service0001
    00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Generic Attribute Profile
Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_50_E3_B6_91_00/service0001/char0002
    00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Service Changed
Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_50_E3_B6_91_00/service0001/char0002/desc0004
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[DIY Page Turner]# select-attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_50_E3_B6_91_00/service005f/char0060
[DIY Page Turner:/service005f/char0060]# read
Attempting to read /org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_50_E3_B6_91_00/service005f/char0060
[CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_50_E3_B6_91_00/service005f/char0060 Value:
  2f                                               /               
  2f                                               /               
[DIY Page Turner:/service005f/char0060]# exit
[fedora@fedora ~]$ echo "Battery Level: $(( 16#2f ))%"
Battery Level: 47%
```

(Not sure if the value (2f) appearing twice is correct behavior, but I assume it is since Linux doesn't seem to have a problem with it.)

On Lineage OS however, it doesn't show that information in the status bar:
[image]

I can display it using BLExplorer though.
[image]
(35 is the battery level percentage in hex. Which, converted to decimal makes 53%, which is accurate. So the battery level is transmitted properly.)

What I would like to see is this btw:
[image]

Comment: Do other devices, for examples earphones, show their battery statuses?

Comment: Yes, with earphones it works as expected.